# How to link flutter with Google Cloud API written in python

Tags: python-3.x, flutter, dart, google-cloud-platform, google-speech-to-text-api

I implemented the speech to text function using python. I used google cloud api as speech to text api. My ultimate goal is to develop an application with speech to text functionality with flutter. I want to load speech to text implemented in python into flutter and put it in the application. How can I do this?

I use a translator so the sentences may be awkward.

[This photo is a test of the speech to text function implemented in python.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogCgX.png)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is quite broad and is challenging to answer succinctly.

IIUC you want to combine a Flutter (framework) app (written in Dart) with a Python app.

It is *probably* not a good idea to `put it in the application`.

The Dart app runs in one process and the Python app runs in another process. It is possible to create a process (e.g. for your Python app) in Dart (using [Process class](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.14.0/dart-io/Process-class.html)) but I advise against this.

If the Python app comprises standalone functionality, one option if you really don't wish to rewrite the Python functionality, is to run the Python app as a server and communicate with it from the Dart app. There are many ways this could be done including using e.g. gRPC.

However, I think the best solution would be for you to rewrite the Python app in Dart and combine the functionality into a single Flutter app.

Google provides a Dart SDK for [Cloud Speech-to-Text API](https://pub.dev/packages/googleapis#cloud-speech-to-text-api). IIUC, there aren't (Google-provided) Cloud Client Libraries available in Dart ([list](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/cloud-client-libraries#by_language)). I assume (!?) that you used the Python SDK for [Cloud Speech-to-Text API](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/dyn/speech_v1.html) and so the conversion to Dart should be relatively straightforward.